# How to apply sound effects like echo, flange etc to music in iphone sdk

Tags: audio, effects, echo, effect

I want to give sound effects like echo, flange etc to a sound in iphone sdk. 
Can anyone help me out how can I achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with ? Interacting with the audio APIs, or generating the effects themselves ?

Comment: I have to play two audio tracks simultaneously by applying sound effects such like echo, flanger to individual audio track. I dont have much experience for working with audio frameworks. 
If you have some sample code, that will be more appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try LittleEndian.com/developers sound effect library, fairly easy to use.